# Does anyone know what kind of algorithm Slic3r uses to generate its toolpath?

Tags: slic3r, algorithm

Is there an algorithm that Slic3r uses to generate the infill? I'm doing a research on toolpath algorithms and improving my prints by the way or controlling the path it takes.

I wasn't too good in searching the right keywords within the source, so it will probably be good if someone could point me to the source code where it works too!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "print its toolpath"? Please be specific about what you want to know, because a description of the entire workings of slic3r would be far too broad for a stackexchange question/answer.